# Why is this tee losing stdout?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, pipe, tee

Simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_ssh_account="depesz@localhost"
directory_to_tar=pgdata
exec nice tar cf - "$directory_to_tar" | \
    tee >(
        md5sum - | \
        ssh "$remote_ssh_account" 'cat - > /tmp/h3po4-MD5-2012-03-13.tar'
    ) | \
    ssh "$remote_ssh_account" 'cat - > /tmp/h3po4-data-2012-03-13.tar'
```

Theoretically it should deliver the data and checksum, to remote machine.

But somehow the tee fails with:

```
tee: standard output: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Did strace, but nothing came out of it. I see both ssh started, and tee writing to both of them, but only the pipe to ( md5sum | ssh ) gets data - strace of the ssh "data" doesn't get any data, and after 5 seconds tee shows the error.

Aside from this all works. 2 connections are established, tar works, md5sum and its delivery works.

Comment: On the `strace` front, try `strace -fF`.  Works like a champ for me.

Comment: -fF is not in manual, but there is -f, -F and -ff. I used `strace -ff -o strace.log -s 512 ./z.sh`

Comment: `-fF` is the same as `-f -F`.  The `-F` is actually unneeded on most of the systems I work on, but it (tries to) follow vforks on older versions of strace, and has no effect on newer ones, but it doesn't hurt.  `-ff` ends up writing a bunch of files (one per PID) that you then have to collate back into a sensible timeline, so I avoid it in the vast majority of situations.  That said, `-ff` should work, but the output files will be oddly-named.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, an alternative way of doing the pipe that breaks:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_ssh_account="depesz@localhost"
directory_to_tar=pgdata
nice tar cf - "$directory_to_tar" | \
    tee >(
        md5sum | \
        ssh "$remote_ssh_account" 'cat > /tmp/h3po4-MD5-2012-03-13.sum'
    ) > >(
        ssh "$remote_ssh_account" 'cat > /tmp/h3po4-data-2012-03-13.tar'
    )
```

Comment: Seems to be working. I still would love to know why the | ssh thing breaks.

Answer (score 6):

Issue found.  Here's the relevant portion of the `strace`:

```
[pid 10243] write(1, "pFl\r\347\345]\244Hi\336\253,-\231\247\344\234\241\332\302\252\315\243G\234\225+\241\323\316s"..., 4096 <unfinished ...>
[pid 10247] select(7, [3 4], [3], NULL, {10, 0} <unfinished ...>
[pid 10243] <... write resumed> )       = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 10247] <... select resumed> )      = 1 (out [3], left {10, 0})
[pid 10243] write(2, "tee: ", 5tee:  <unfinished ...>
(...)
[pid 10243] write(2, "standard output", 15standard output <unfinished ...>
(...)
[pid 10243] write(2, ": Resource temporarily unavailab"..., 34: Resource temporarily unavailable) = 34
```

So, what's happening is that the remote ssh isn't yet ready for the write to continue.  Most programs handle this correctly, but tee decides to die in a pile.  See http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2012-February/047528.html for one reference to this sort of behavior.  There are a couple others that I found too in a brief search for "EAGAIN tee".

The solution that lhunath found works because it effectively forces bash to handle the `EAGAIN`.  Elegant.

Comment: Same error - you can also easily test it yourself - just change directory to tar (it shouldn't be too small), and remote_ssh_account - to something that you have passwordless access to.

Comment: Changed; please try again.  Yes, I know that doesn't do exactly what you want, but I just want to try it.  Please be sure you're running it the same way (i.e., as a script, not directly on the command line).

Comment: This works, and delivers the file. While I do appreciate the help - tests like this can be ran everywhere - did my original script *not* fail for you?

Comment: I can get the problem to reliably recur with `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=20 | tee >(md5sum - | ssh user@host 'cat - > /tmp/foo.md5') | ssh user@host 'cat > /tmp/foo.tar'`.  Working on debugging why now.

Comment: It also happens with the order reversed (that is, with the `cat>tar` inside the `>()`).  Neat.  Adding the `-i` flag to `tee` (on a blind hunch) didn't help.

Comment: Yeah - it looks that the pipe before final ssh breaks. removing it to use > >( ), as in lhunath example - helps, but also helps if I'll do: `tee >( md5sum | ssh ) >( ssh ) > /dev/null` Weird stuff.

Comment: Since the evolution of my answer can be confusing to read: I've updated my answer with the final analysis of why this failed in the first place.