# Debugging rsync over SSH in verbose mode using tee to redirect stdout to log file

Tags: ssh, bash, rsync, stdout, tee

I have been having issues with various rsync operations over SSH, on a particular machine on our network, failing and giving errors like:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (45482 bytes received so far)  [generator]
```

I found a similar post ([rsync - unexplained error](https://serverfault.com/questions/812781/rsync-unexplained-error/877756#877756)) for which one of the answers suggested running the SSH command used by rsync in verbose mode and redirecting the output, in my case as follows:

```
rsync -av -e 'bash -x -c "ssh -p 22 -vvvv $0 $@ 2>/tmp/rsync-ssh.stderr | tee /tmp/rsync.stdout"' --rsync-path='sudo rsync' "backup_user@10.0.0.2:/media/remote_volume/" "/media/local_volume"
```

This rsync command seems to run fine for a while but eventually fails with the error:

```
tee: standard output: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I am guessing it is likely failing for a similar reason as is described in the answer to the following question: [Why is this tee losing stdout?](https://serverfault.com/questions/369757/why-is-this-tee-losing-stdout) However, it doesn't seem clear to me how I should change the SSH command in my case to remidy the issue.

Does anyone know way of making SSH play nice with tee in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done a bit more reading on the solution discussed in the answer to the question "[Why is this tee losing stdout?](https://serverfault.com/questions/369757/why-is-this-tee-losing-stdout)", it seems like the crucial change is replacing the pipe with redirection to a subshell containing the command that would otherwise be being piped into. (Thus, replacing: `command1 | command2` with: `command1 > >( command2 )`)

The reason for this is that by redirecting to a subshell, rather than directly piping into the next command, one is forcing the subshell to handle any `EAGAIN` [error codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) returned. As discussed in this FreeBSD message board message: [bin/164947: tee looses data when writing to non-blocking file descriptors](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2012-February/047528.html) (also linked in the answer to the other question) `tee` and other system binaries can be quite bad at handling retries themselves.

For the `rsync` command above, the following alterations seem to fix my original issue:

```
rsync -av -e 'bash -x -c "ssh -p 22 -vvvv $0 $@ 2>/tmp/rsync-ssh.stderr > >( tee /tmp/rsync.stdout )"' --rsync-path='sudo rsync' "backup_user@10.0.0.2:/media/remote_volume/" "/media/local_volume"
```